# "dispatch" is not a function error

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am having problems with redux.  I'm trying to dispatch a value from a search bar I created that will get the client ID of who I type in.  The auto-suggestion works fine. The Item (ID Number) and value (Client name) correctly in the console log.  but I am unable to dispatch it to the reducer. I keep getting a "dispatch" is not a function error. Redux is imported. Any Ideas?

```
class ClientSearch extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
    }

  lowerCase = (str) => {
    console.log(str);
    return str;
  }

  test = (value, item) => {
    console.log('Inside Test',item.numClientID);

    let { dispatch } = this.props
     dispatch(fetchClient(item.numClientID))
  }
}
  render() {
    let value = '';
      return (
        <div>
          <ReactAutocomplete
            items={this.props.clients}
            shouldItemRender={(item, value) => item.txtName.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1}
            getItemValue={(item) => item.txtName}
            renderItem={(item, highlighted) =>
                <div
                  key={item.numClientID}
                  style={{ backgroundColor: highlighted ? 'purple' : 'transparent'}}
                >
                {item.txtName}
                </div>           
            }
            value={this.state.selectedClient}
            onChange={e => this.setState({ selectedClient: e.target.value })}
            onSelect={(value, item) => this.test(value,item)}
          />
        </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log('map state', state)
  return {

    clients: state.client.clients
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, dispatch =>
  bindActionCreators(listClients, dispatch, fetchClient, dispatch)
)(ClientSearch);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing it like this.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
  clients: state.client.clients
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  fooAction: (payload) => dispatch(foo(payload)),
  barAction: () => dispatch(bar()),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ClientSearch);
```

Here `foo()` and `bar()` are actions that get dispatched so for example the method `foo()` can be defined and declared like this.

```
function foo(payload) {
  return dispatch => SOME_API_METHOD(payload)
   .then(response => {
     dispatch({
       type: 'SOME_COOL_ACTION_NAME',
       info: response
     });
   })
}
```

For reference have a look at [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux) Along with [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk)

Answer (score 1):

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log('map state', state)
  return {

    clients: state.client.clients
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, dispatch=>bindActionCreators({listClients, fetchClient},dispatch))(ClientSearch);
This should work for you
```